# How to retrieve the selected date in window phone application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, datepicker

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the window phone 7 application development. I have added the datepicker control to my application. Now I am able to select the required date whichever I want. I want to submit some information in my application through the Submit button along with the date selected through the datepicker. But I am unaware of how to retrieve the selected date. I am using the following code

```
<toolkit:DatePicker ValueChanged="DatePicker_ValueChanged" Margin="296,0,0,552" />
```

Now I have the following function

```
 private void DatePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

In the above function how should I retrive the date which is selected from the application ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give a name to your DatePicker:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Name="MyDate" ValueChanged="DatePicker_ValueChanged" Margin="296,0,0,552" />
```

Then, in your code-behind:

```
var date = (DateTime) MyDate.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs` that are provided in the `e` argument.

```
private void DatePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, 
                                     DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var date = e.NewDateTime;
}
```